# does this regex combination match to an ipv4 address

Tags: c, regex, networking

im having a hard time trying to create and find a good ipv4 regex match but all i can find is this:

```
(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})
```

does this regex combination match to something like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` or `xx.xxx.x.x` etc? I'm trying to make a connection to a web server by pinging via domain name to get the ip but when i try it, the code returns that there is not match. here is the ping command btw:

```
PING google.com (172.217.1.14): 56 data bytes
```

Comment: `{1,3}` means to match between 1 and 3 instances of the previous pattern. So `\d{1,3}` will match `1`, `12`, or `123`.

Comment: What regexp engine are you using? If you're using basic regular expressions, it doesn't recognize the `\d` escape sequence. Use `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: Barmar, isnt {1,3} a quantifier?

Comment: Yes. A quantifier is used to specify how many of the previous pattern to match.

Comment: i thought it would do something like count anything like xxx.xxx.xx.xxx or x.xx.x.x

Comment: It will, since there are between 1 and 3 digits in each segment of the address.

Comment: But you need to replace `\d` with `[0-9]` to match digits.

Comment: okay, i was confused for a second. sorry about that

Comment: it still doesnt work when i change \d to [0-9]

Comment: You might need to select extended regular expression to get `{1,3}` quantifiers.

Comment: Or you can install the PCRE library and use your original regexp.

Comment: If using basic REs, the curly braces have to be escaped: `[0-9]\{1,3\}`

Comment: However, this will match things like 999.999.999.999 that aren't valid IP addresses. You might consider using `inet_aton()` or something for further validation if that's important to catch.

Comment: But this seems like it might be an XY problem. If you want to resolve a hostname to an IP address, use `getaddrinfo()`!

Answer (score 0):

256.1.1.1 9.900.0.0 etc. are not valid, this parses those out w/o back-tracking (to prevent RE-DoS):

```
egrep '^((0|1[0-9]{0,2}|2([0-4][0-9]{0,1}|5[0-5]{0,1}|[6-9]){0,1}|[3-9][0-9]{0,1})\.){3}(0|1[0-9]{0,2}|2([0-4][0-9]{0,1}|5[0-5]{0,1}|[6-9]){0,1}|[3-9][0-9]{0,1})$'
```